# IOS CoreBluetooth API Misuse with Google Nearby

Tags: ios, beacon, google-nearby

So when I launch google nearby on my ios device I get the following:

[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE:  has no restore identifier but the delegate implements the centralManager:willRestoreState: method. Restoring will not be supported

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You'll find all kinds of strange messages when you start digging into logs!  If you are not directly using CoreBluetooth, then I would ignore this message.  It probably means exactly what it says, that Nearby for iOS implements only half of the contract needed for bluetooth state restoration.  Since there are no serious consequences, the fact that this appears in the log is no more than a slight annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong.  This API misuse warning is unavoidable because the Nearby Messages library supports both foreground and background BLE scanning/advertising, and therefore implements the centralManager:willRestoreState: method. Apps that don't enable BLE background scanning will unfortunately see this warning.